# Allocating memory that can be freed by the OS if needed

Tags: c++, caching, memory-management

I'm writing a program that generates thumbnails for every page in a large document.  For performance reasons I would like to keep the thumbnails in memory for as long as possible, but I would like the OS to be able to reclaim that memory if it decides there is another more important use for it (e.g. the user has started running a different application.)

I can always regenerate the thumbnail later if the memory has gone away.

Is there any cross-platform method for flagging memory as can-be-removed-if-needed?  The program is written in C++.

---

EDIT: Just to clarify, rather than being notified when memory is low or regularly monitoring the system's amount of memory, I'm thinking more along the lines of allocating memory and then "unlocking" it when it's not in use.  The OS can then steal unlocked memory if needed (even for disk buffers if it thinks that would be a better use of the memory) and all I have to do as a programmer is just "lock" the memory again before I intend to use it.  If the lock fails I know the memory has been reused for something else so I need to regenerate the thumbnail again, and if the lock succeeds I can just keep using the data from before.

The reason is I might be displaying maybe 20 pages of a document on the screen, but I may as well keep thumbnails of the other 200 or so pages in case the user scrolls around a bit.  But if they go do something else for a while, that memory might be better used as a disk cache or for storing web pages or something, so I'd like to be able to tell the OS that it can reuse some of my memory if it wants to.

Having to monitor the amount of free system-wide memory may not achieve the goal (my memory will never be reclaimed to improve disk caching), and getting low-memory notifications will only help in emergencies.  I was hoping that by having a lock/unlock method, this could be achieved in more of a lightweight way and benefit the performance of the system in a non-emergency situation.

Comment: *Just to clarify, rather than being notified when memory is low or regularly monitoring the system's amount of memory, I'm thinking more along the lines of allocating memory and then "unlocking" it when it's not in use.* What benefit is there to release the memory except in a low memory scenario? If memory is not low, why wouldn't the operating system/another application take more for its own caching purposes? This seems like a case of premature optimisation.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Imagine you have 4GB RAM and the thumbnails take up 1GB.  Then there is plenty of free memory so all is fine.  But imagine you are on a system with only 2GB RAM.  Using 1GB for thumbnails might be ok if this is the only application running, but since there will be very little free memory it would be nice if the OS could claim back the entire 1GB if you go load a web browser, for instance.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any cross-platform method for flagging memory as can-be-removed-if-needed? The program is written in C++

For Windows, at least, you can [register for a memory resource notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/desktop/aa366541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
HANDLE WINAPI CreateMemoryResourceNotification(
  _In_  MEMORY_RESOURCE_NOTIFICATION_TYPE NotificationType
);
```

> `NotificationType`
>
> - `LowMemoryResourceNotification` Available physical memory is running low.
> - `HighMemoryResourceNotification` Available physical memory is high.

Just be careful responding to *both* events. You might create a feedback loop (*memory is low, release the thumbnails!* and then *memory is high, make all the thumbnails!*).

Comment: What are the ranges of physical memory in which both the notifications are signalled?

Answer (score 2):

In AIX, there is a signal SIGDANGER that is send to applications when available memory is low. You may handle this signal and free some memory.

There is a discussion among Linux people to implement this feature into Linux. But AFAIK it is not yet implemented in Linux. Maybe they think that application should not care about low level memory management, and it could be transparently handled in OS via swapping.

In posix standard there is a function `posix_madvise` might be used to mark an area of memory as less important. There is an advice `POSIX_MADV_DONTNEED` specifies that the application expects that it will not access the specified range in the near future.

But unfortunately, current Linux implementation will immediately free the memory range when  `posix_madvise` is called with this advice.

So there's no portable solution to your question.

However, on almost every OS you are able to read the current available memory via some OS interface. So you can routinely read such value and manually free memory when available memory in OS is low.

Comment: Are you sure about this? maybe you're confusing with `madvise()+MADV_DONTNEED` which in Linux, in fact, will free the pages you specify, while instead `posix_madvise()+POSIX_MADV_DONTNEED` won't free the pages, but it will leave the memory intact to the user

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special you need to do. The OS will remove things from memory if they haven't been used recently automatically. Some OSes have platform-specific ways to improve this, but generally, nothing special is needed.

Comment: *The OS will remove things from memory if they haven't been used recently automatically.* I assume you mean the page file. It sounds like OP wants to generate as many thumbnails before affecting performance of the whole machine. But if he does *nothing special* then he's just going to fill up the page file.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Presumably he's on a server class machine with plenty of page file. He can have a configurable limit if he wants, it's hard to say without making guesses about the specifics of his application.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very similar and has answers that cover things not covered here.
[Allocating "temporary" memory (in Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22421014/allocating-temporary-memory-in-linux)

This shouldn't be too hard to do because this is exactly what the page cache does, using unused memory to cache the hard disk. In theory, someone could write a filesystem such that when you read from a certain file, it calculated something, and the page cache would cache it automatically.

All the basics of automatically freed cache space are already there in any OS with a disk cache, and It's hard to imagine there not being an API for something that would make a huge difference especially in things like mobile web browsers.